# PostgreSQL - create cast from text to integer throws max_stack_depth error

Tags: postgresql, casting

In PostgreSQL 10 I need to execute such an SQL command:

```
select id from table1 where id='859'::text
```

Of course it could cause an error, so I've created such a CAST:

```
CREATE FUNCTION to_int(text) 
  RETURNS integer 
  STRICT IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE SQL AS 
'SELECT cast($1 as integer);';

CREATE CAST (text AS integer) WITH FUNCTION to_int(text) as Implicit;
```

But, after executing `select id from table1 where id='859'::text` command, PostgreSQL throws an exception `max_stack_depth`.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: The correct solution to your problem is to use a matching number constant: `select id from table1 where id=859`

Comment: The cast already exists, there is no need to *improve* it. **Never** try to create an **implicit** cast from `text`. Even if you knew how to do this, the consequences would be deplorable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call is endlessly recursive. In your cast function, you call a cast.

You get the error because this endless loop hits the maximum possible recursion depth.

Read [this old blog post](https://petereisentraut.blogspot.com/2008/03/readding-implicit-casts-in-postgresql.html) to see how you can create such a cast correctly.

The best thing, however, is not to do that and fix your code. These casts were removed for a reason; they create ambiguities.